# make asp.net server control cross browser compatible

Tags: .net, asp.net, javascript, html, css

How can i make asp.net control cross browser compatible?
it is compatible with IE only.
Let me know the best steps to do this.

Comment: Please, show some code of your control.

Comment: Which control - one of the standard controls or a custom control you have written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot change the source code for the control you can still change it's rendering by implementing a `ControlAdapter` derived class.
A `ControlAdapter` allows you to override how a control is rendered, making it compatible with more browsers or more suitable for css styling. For ASP.Net 2.0 Microsoft released a package of [CSS Friendly Control Adapters](http://www.asp.net/cssadapters/) that you may want to look at.

Answer (score 0):

Use firebug to see which properties of the control behave differently in Firefox, and update them to standards.

Answer (score 0):

I think ASP.NET controls are cross browser compatible. The issue occurs when control are placed on page & page is rendered. This can be fixed either by modifying inline style or by using css files.